# How to pass views link as a variable to a node?

Tags: 7, views

I have had a custom tables and I need them to view using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) in Drupal 7 module and it works.

In the Views module we can output fields as a link and redirect to the page what we need and I did this.

My question: when that link is clicked by the user, I need the link name to go to the specific node that I want as variable and being accessed by that node.

Is that possible in Drupal 7?

Comment: `I need the link name to go to the specific node that I want as variable and being accessed by that node` I don't fully understand this part. Can you re-word it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Rules Link](https://drupal.org/project/rules_link) module to generate a custom link that can trigger a rule (from the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module). So that via the Rules module you can then implement your logic about the "specific node and that variable" that you mentioned in your question.

Some more details about the [Rules Link](https://drupal.org/project/rules_link) module (from its project page):

> This module lets you create links which trigger arbitrary functionality with the help of Rules.
>
> Features
>
> - Attach the link to any entities.
> - Show the link only for certain bundles.
> - Narrow the entities on which the link will be shown using the visibility conditions.
> - The links are usually displayed using Views.
> - For entities that can be displayed, the links can be shown on node view.
> - Supports an arbitrary number of additional Rules parameters for passing context via Views.
> - 3 types of links: Javascript, Normal and Confirmation form links.
> - Use individual permissions for each link.